# Show/hide div on scroll with JQuery WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a social bar at the bottom of the screen on my site but I want to display it only after the user scrolls a little and hide it once the user is about to reach the footer. So around 200px before the page ends.+

This is my div:

```
<div class="sticky-bar-hr">
.......
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.sticky-bar-hr{
    display: none;
}
```

And this is the JQuery I am trying:

```
 <script> 
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $('.sticky-bar-hr').fadeOut();
  } else {
    $('.sticky-bar-hr').fadeIn();
  }
});
</script>
```

But it does not work. The problem seems to be that the function is not being called. I am setting the script in my homepage HTML in Wordpress

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try logging scroll event itself, to see if its even calling. If that works, then try logging y, to see if that ever reaches 800+. Because script logic looks ok

Comment: The event is not being called. If I place a alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!"); inside the function it doesn't show it. What can I do?

Comment: Maybe you need `$( document ).ready(function() { and then scroll here? });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
 var y = $(this).scrollTop();
 if(y<200) {
  $('.sticky-bar-hr').fadeOut();
 }
 if (y > 200) {
  $('.sticky-bar-hr').fadeIn();
 } 
 if(y+ $(this).height() == $(document).height()) {
  $('.sticky-bar-hr').fadeOut();
 }
});
```

```css
body {
 height: 2000px;
}
.sticky-bar-hr {
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background:#000;
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sticky-bar-hr">
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you have inverted `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $('.sticky-bar-hr').fadeOut();
  } else {
    $('.sticky-bar-hr').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
.sticky-bar-hr{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sticky-bar-hr">
.......
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Problem is I can't get the function to work. I place an alert inside it and it never shows anything. Why could this be?

Comment: There's something in Wordpress that "kills" your js code.